# Metabase returns as killed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, metabase

Trying to run metabase in a server with 1 GB of RAM.  I run below statement

```
java -jar metabase.jar
```

It returns below as

```
08-29 17:00:59 INFO metabase.util :: Loading Metabase...
Killed
```

I could not find any logs

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Are you using a VPS? I'm in an LXC and wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

What other services are you running?

Potentially the answer could be “Buy more RAM” see http://discourse.metabase.com/t/metbase-killed/2924

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Java runtime environment exhaust available memory and gets killed.
You can try defining how much memory it should use by passing the -Xmx argument to the Java runtime environment:

Example:`java -Xmx512m -jar metabase.jar`